# Does AutoML accept external models?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, automl

I used random search and got the best hyper parameters for my model, can I pass that model to the AutoML?

Does AutoML do the random search for the best hyper parameters by itself? or is there something I need to pass?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're referring to **Google Cloud AutoML**. It is a cloud-based Machine Learning (ML) platform that suggests a no-code approach to building data-driven solutions. AutoML was designed to build custom models for both newcomers and experienced machine learning engineers.

For newcomers, you could use **Vertex AI** (fully automated) to build a ML model:
[image]

For experienced ML engineers, you could also use **AutoML Tabular** to build a custom model, with the ability to select a model and input the selected hyperparameters:
[image]

You can read more details from [here](https://cloud.google.com/automl)

Comment: I'm curious of how you found my question after 7 months? Thank you for answering!

Comment: I'm learning and searching for info, then I chanced into this question. I thought I might as well apply my newly learnt knowledge, haha!

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer.. would you be able to upvote as well, if you dont mind :-) haha, you will be helping me get the "machine-learning" badge, because i'm only missing 1 vote, thanks thanks!

Comment: I wanted to, but I didn't have enough reputation, now I suddenly can after you replied :)

Comment: you've just gained 2 more points today, how timely! hahaha

Comment: Congrats on getting the badge you deserve it

Comment: Hey thanks! I've just got awarded that badge today... Yay!!! Do ping me when you have other ML questions or Python questions, I'd try to answer them, cheers!